# Haskell type inference with Read

Tags: haskell, type-inference

I think I have a problem with Haskell type inference.

I made my own data type and made it instance of the class `Read`. My data type is actually take an other type as parameter, it's a type parameter.

I redefined `readPresc` in a way that parse the string and give back my new data. When I write:

```
read "string that represent MyType a" :: MyType a
```

it works perfectly fine (at least it does what I expected)

Now I have a function, let's call it `insert`, that takes an element of type `a`, `MyType a`, and gives back a new `MyTape a`.

```
insert :: a -> MyType a -> a
```

but when I write:

```
insert 3 "string that rapresent MyType Int"
```

I got `Ambigous type`.

How can I tell haskell to infer to the `read` the same type that is the parameter of the insert?

Comment: Do you mean `insert 3 (read "string representation")`?

Comment: Also, can you clarify a little? `read "bla blah blah" :: MyType` suggests `MyType` is a type, but `insert :: a -> MyType a -> a` implies `MyType` is a type constructor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How can I tell haskell to infer to the `read` the same type that is the parameter of the insert?

You don't need to, that is inferred from the type of `insert`.

The problem is that in

```
insert 3 (read "string that rapresent MyType Int" )
```

(I inserted the `read` for it to be possibly type correct), the literal `3` is polymorphic. Its type is

```
3 :: Num a => a
```

so that is still not enough information to determine what type `read` should produce, hence the error.

You need to provide the necessary information, for example

```
insert (3 :: Int) (read "string that rapresent MyType Int" )
```

or by using the result in a context that determines the type variable `a`.